# WPA2 Enterprise EAP PEAP inconsistency across devices

Tags: wifi-configuration

My apartment has free WiFi provided by some company. I was made to give them a call, and they had me set up a username and password. They then told me to connect my devices to the network with those credentials, and also told me that it wouldn’t work for MacBooks and that that can’t be fixed. I didn’t believe them, but sure enough, here are my results.

iPhone 8 Plus: works

Android (galaxy S5): works

Newer MacBook Pro (2018?): works

My late 2012 MacBook Pro: worked for about 2 minutes, now it never works

2010 Mac mini: I think I got it to connect once, but it was really short! It never connects basically.

I know that there is a lot more investigation to be done. But if there’s anything I should know about WPA2 that would help please let me know.

Comment: Did they mention which specific EAP method is used? Do they provide Linux or WinXP instructions (which would contain this information)? The problem with EAP is that it's _very_ flexible...

Comment: @grawity They didn't. Is there a way I can tell which EAP method it is?

Edit: I believe it was EAP PEAP based on something I saw in the network logs...not sure. I'll double check around lunch today.